# UIPageViewController in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

**UPDATE**

In my `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, I can get things working if I do this:

```
[self addChildViewController:scroller];
[cell.contentView addSubview:scroller.view];
[scroller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

However, now because of cell reuse, if I swipe the first row over 5 images, then scroll the table down so the first row is offscreen, when I scroll back up to the first row, that slideshow has reset back to the first image.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I have a UITableView that take up the entire width/height of the screen.

In each cell, I want the user to be able to scroll horizontally through a set of images.

I'm using UIPageViewController to handle the scrolling and lazy loading. I can get my first image to load perfectly, but then when I try to scroll to the next image, none of the UIPageViewController's dataSource methods are being called.

If I remove the dataSource methods completely, the images in each cell don't scroll/move at all. However, with the dataSource methods in place, I can at least get a bouncing movement, but nothing gets loaded before or after.

In `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
// MyScrollerPageViewController is a subclass of UIPageViewController
MyScrollerPageViewController *scroller = [[MyScrollerPageViewController alloc] initWithItems:self.items];
[cell.contentView addSubview:scroller.view];
```

In `MyScrollerPageViewController` (a subclass of UIPageViewController)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.dataSource = self;
    self.delegate = self;

    MyImageViewController *viewController = [[MyImageViewController alloc] initWithImage:self.items[0]];
    [self setViewControllers:@[viewController]
                   direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                    animated:false
                  completion:nil];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    // THIS NEVER GETS CALLED
    NSLog(@"BEFORE!");
    return nil;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    // THIS NEVER GETS CALLED
    NSLog(@"AFTER!");
    return nil;
}
```

To reiterate, I can get the first image loading fine, which tells me my subclass of UIPageViewController is loading it's first viewController fine. I just can't get it's datasource methods to fire, which means no other viewControllers load.

Comment: Does it work outside of the UITableView? Is the UITableView relevant?

Comment: That's what I was just trying to figure out. All of this is happening inside MasterViewController. That's where my tableView is defined in a xib. If I remove the tableView and just instantiate MyScrollerPageViewController in Master's `viewDidLoad` and do `[self.view addSubview:scroller.view] it still doesn't work. However, if I add MySCrollerPageViewController as a child view controller to Master, add the view, and say `didMoveToParentViewController`, I get the before/after delegate calls and things seem to work fine. Not sure what to make of that.